# Accessing parent.window.pageYOffset

Tags: javascript, facebook

I need to center an overlay inside Facebook tab. The problem is that in order to do that I need to know parent window `pageYOffset`. I cannot access it due to the same origin policy restrictions.

Does Facebook API provide alternative way to get this information?

If not, then how would you center the overlay?

Answer (score 0):

The information provided by FB.Canvas.getPageInfo should help you to calculate this:
https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/javascript/FB.Canvas.getPageInfo/